# SQL PDO Wrong syntax near "@P1"

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdo, syntax-error, limit

I try to use LIMIT with PDO SQL.

My code is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TblWerte LIMIT :limit1";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':limit1', $limit1);
$limit1 = 15;
$result->execute();
```

But when I write $result->execute(); I keep getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Falsche Syntax
>   in der Nähe von "@P1". in C:...\werte.php:96
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\...\werte.php(96): PDOStatement->execute()
>
> 1 {main}
>
> thrown in C:\...\werte.php on line 96

The line 96 is "$result->execute();"

I already tried different this like using `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`, I tried to directly parse the value `"limit1"` into an integer in `bindParam()` ...

**The solution**
I had to use TOP instead of LIMIT. Also I had to remove the bindParams() part.

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 15 * FROM TblWerte ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: the error message doesn't seem to be related the the code posted. Let alone SQL server doesn't support LIMIT. Something is very wrong here

Comment: Actually a part of the code was wrong (see the solution in my edited post). I also hat to change LIMIT (see the first answer of Gabriel Durac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LIMIT` clause is not part of standard SQL. It's supported as a vendor extension to SQL by MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite.
SQL Server has something similar: `TOP`

```
$sql = "SELECT top :limit1 * FROM TblWerte";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':limit1 ', $limit1);
$limit1 = 15;
$result->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it like you wrote it, but same error :/

Comment: Hello, I finally figured out the problem. Your answer is working well. The problem was result->bindParam. I posted the solution in the original post.